# How do I place the "follow active quads" results against the UV Grid?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Below is a view of my dinner plate.  The green faces traveling around the blue center of the plate, display as a circular image the UV image, and do not texture correctly.  So I thought I would try to use "follow active quads" just for those green faces.  At first it appeared to work, as it gave me the flat non-circular grid you see on the UV grid.  But I see no way to rotate it so it will lie flat against the UV grid.  I made one face active, then using circle select, I selected all the other green faces.  The I pressed U for unwrap, and chose "follow active quads" and ok.  Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong, or have not gone far enough?  I would appreciate any advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the UV coordinates, before using *Follow active quads*.
I don't know why :).

1. Select the faces (<kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to select the whole island)
2. Go *UV > Reset* to clear the UV coordinates
3. Unwrap through *UV > Follow Active quads*.

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks for this answer!

Comment: Happy to help :). I learned something new myself.