# After marking seem, uv-unwrap checkmap showing distorted

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to unwrap the cylinder using "u" -> unwrap after marking seam along the vertical axis as shown in the picture (1). When I apply checker map on it to see the stretching or distortion, I found that the the checker map is distorted as shown in picture(2).

I have tried to apply scale, all transformations but no success. I have no idea why is it happening. Can anyone suggest me the way out. thanks

File shared here - https://easyupload.io/n4clhh

Pic (1)
[image]

Pic 2
[image]

Mark Seem along vertical
[image]

Comment: Can youi add picture on which you will show how your UVMap look's like in UV editor for that part of cylinder

Comment: also please share your object, maybe use the Follow Active Quads unwrap option?

Comment: @moonboots- link has been shared. can you see it pls ? thanks

Comment: Thanks, It has solved my problem actually - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173652/how-do-i-place-the-follow-active-quads-results-against-the-uv-grid